# Web API 2 Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have this API method:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Users")]
    string GetUsers()
    {
        return "Aye";
    }
}
```

And this routing in config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

I host the API on IIS (localhost:8000) , give the site all the required permissions and when I try to call http://localhost:8000/Users it says:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Please help.

Comment: Do you call WebApiConfig.Register method from Application_StartUp in Global.asax?

Comment: protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller action should be defined as `public`, but your has no access modifier, so it is internal.

Comment: I can't belive I missed this. Thanks !